# uitextfield and uilabel depends on checkmark

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uilabel

In my tableview containing 8 row datas, I want to show the 8 label and 8 textfield in otherview, for ex: If the user selects(checkmarked) 4 rows in uitableview means I want to show 4 label and 4 texfield in other view. Can any one help me for this logic?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    [lb5 setHidden:YES];
    [text5 setHidden:YES];
    [lb6 setHidden:YES];
    [text6 setHidden:YES];
    //[lb7 setHidden:YES];
    //[text7 setHidden:YES];
    //[lb8 setHidden:YES];
    //[text8 setHidden:YES];

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 678)];

    int s=[am.genar count];
    am=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"test %d",[am.genar count]);
    NSLog(@"test %@",[am.genar objectAtIndex:0]);
    lb1.text=[am.genar objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"test %@",[am.genar objectAtIndex:1]);
    lb2.text=[am.genar objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"test %@",[am.genar objectAtIndex:2]);
    lb3.text=[am.genar objectAtIndex:2]; 
    NSLog(@"test %@",[am.genar objectAtIndex:3]);
    lb4.text=[am.genar objectAtIndex:3]; 

    if(s>3)
    {
       [lb5 setHidden:NO];
       [text5 setHidden:NO];
        [lb6 setHidden:NO];
        [text6 setHidden:NO];
       // [lb7 setHidden:NO];
      //  [text7 setHidden:NO];
      //  [lb8 setHidden:NO];
      //  [text8 setHidden:NO];;
        NSLog(@"test %@",[am.genar objectAtIndex:4]);
        lb5.text=[am.genar objectAtIndex:4];   
        NSLog(@"test %@",[am.genar objectAtIndex:5]);
        lb6.text=[am.genar objectAtIndex:5]; 
       // NSLog(@"test %@",[am.genar objectAtIndex:6]);
       // lb7.text=[am.genar objectAtIndex:6]; 
       // NSLog(@"test %@",[am.genar objectAtIndex:7]);
       // lb8.text=[am.genar objectAtIndex:7];
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

right now I'm using this logic for showing texfield and label, but it showing error if user selects 5 rows and it's working 6 rows. can any help me to clear?

Comment: @venkat i added the coding pls help me to clear

Comment: after u r adding the value to the am.genar have tried to print the values., if yes means how it was like???

Comment: @dhanush i got the answer from A-Live ,thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your application design it might have sense to use the table  view in the second view controller, it will be easy to create as many rows as needed and display the titles correctly.

If you need to use the outlet labels and textfields, i'd make it like

```
NSArray * arrayOfLabelsAndTextViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:lb1, text1, lb2, text2, lb3, text3, lb4, text4, lb5, text5, lx6, text6, lb7, text7, lb8, text8, nil];
```

With the help of this array you can quickly enumerate through all the label/text pairs accessing it as:

- i      - pair index
- i*2    - label index
- i*2 +1 - text index

Then you need to show exactly the number of pairs checked at the previos view:

```
am=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

const int totalPairsCount = 8;
for(int i = 0; i<totalPairsCount; i++) {

   UILabel * pairLabel =   [arrayOfLabelsAndTextViews objectAtIndex:i*2];
   UITextView * pairText = [arrayOfLabelsAndTextViews objectAtIndex:i*2 +1];
   BOOL isPairVisible = i < am.count;
   if (isPairVisible) {
      pairLabel.text = [am objectAtIndex:i];
      pairText.text = @"";
   }
   pairLabel.hidden = !isPairVisible;
   pairText.hidden = !isPairVisible;
}
```

I don't think that is production quality code but at list it must help you understand how do you operate the data and use the UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

dont code like this..,

```
int s=[am.genar count];
 am=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

add S values after declaration of AppDelegate Variable.,

```
 am=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  int s=[am.genar count];
```

and try to print the values.,.

Answer (score 0):

On Click of Check Mark add that particular string to an Global Array. From that you can get an Global array count 
In Second View

View Did Load Method
create a for loop

```
(int i =0 ; i < appDelegate.globalArray; i++)
{
  Here you can create a label Dynamically whatever number will be. your labels will create according to that
}
```

if you have any questions feel free to ask

Comment: It doesnt make sense, if he has the array he has the count of checked elements, if he doesn't have the array the only checked items count is useless as the check order is random.